# Powershell Active Directory Scripting - Bulk disable with change of display name

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I am looking for assistance in creating/completing a Powershell script that grabs a user's samAccountName from a .csv file, disables that user in a specific domain, e.g. "foo.bar", and then prepends their AD display name with a single character. This is a bulk disable script, and it has to add that single character to the front/beginning of their display name.

What I have so far is:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

$Server = read-host "Enter Domain to query/domain controller" 

Import-Csv "C:\Temp\samAccountNames.csv" | ForEach-Object { 

     $samAccountName = $_."samAccountName" 

     Get-ADUser -Server $Server -Identity $samAccountName | Disable-ADAccount
}
```

Now, what I need to do is to prepend the display name with the '#' character.

(e.g. "Doe, John" becomes "#Doe, John")

Comment: I don't get what specific character should be prepended to the `Display Name` but you're on the good path. Just need to use `Set-ADUser` on the next line. Something to note is that there is no need to query a specific domain controller as disabling them will replicate across the domain.

Comment: I'm really only need to add the '#' character added to the beginning of each disabled user. So, if their display name is "Doe, John", it would now read "#Doe, John".

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the user can be found at all first, then update the displayname and disable the account

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 

$characterToPrepend = '#'  # the character you want to prepend the DisplayName with

$Server = Read-Host "Enter Domain to query/domain controller" 

Import-Csv "C:\Temp\samAccountNames.csv" | ForEach-Object { 
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Server $Server -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$($_.samAccountName)'" -Properties DisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($ADUser) {
        # test if the user is not already disabled
        if (!$ADUser.Enabled) {
            Write-Host "User '$($_.samAccountName)' is already disabled"
        }
        else {
            $newDisplayName = $characterToPrepend + $ADUser.DisplayName
            # set the new displayname and disable the user
            $ADUser | Set-ADUser -DisplayName $newDisplayName -Enabled $false
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User '$($_.samAccountName)' does not exist"
    }
}
```

<sup>I'm using `-Filter` to get the user rather than the `-Identity` parameter because the latter will throw an exception when a user with that SamAccountName could not be found</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I already have a script to check the status of the users, and to export the list to a csv file, so I already know if they are disabled or not, but this single script is far easier, for certain. Thank you for your assistance!